# Changing user input in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am trying to find a way to alter a user's input if they use certain symbols. For example if they type a "<" I want to change it to "less than". Is there a way to set some kind of helper js to apply to all textinputs?

Comment: Probably easier with javascript...

Comment: That is what I thought, but I was not sure of how to set it up on a textboxfor element.

Comment: Just assign an id to the textboxfor and add your Javascript hooks to that id.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used the magic of jQuery to do it.

```
$(':text').change(function() {
            var jQuerySelector = `#${this.id}`;
            var text = $(jQuerySelector).val();
            if (text.includes('<')) {
                text = text.replace('<', 'less than ');
                $(jQuerySelector).val(text);
            }
        });
```